# ASP.NET Web API 2 with using Entity Framework in a separate project

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am implementing a ASP.NET Web API 2. I have created my ADO.NET Entity Data Model in a separate project called `MyEFDataAccess`. I have added this as a reference to MyAPI project.

In `MyAPI` project, I have created the following model:

```
namespace MyAPI.Models
{
  [Table("Customer")]
  public class CustomerViewModel
  {
    [Key]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
}
```

I have created the Context class in `MyAPI` like this:

```
namespace MyAPI.Models
{
   public class CustomerDbContext : DbContext
   {
      public CustomerDbContext() : base("name=CusetomerDbContext")
      {
      }

      public DbSet<MyEFDataAccess.Customer> CustomerViewModel { get; set; }
   }
}
```

I then have created the following controller for customers in the `MyAPI` project:

```
namespace MyAPI.Controllers
{
   public class CustomersController : ApiController
   {
      private readonly CustomerDbContext _context = new CustomerDbContext();

      // GET: api/Customer
      public async Task<List<CustomerViewModel>> GetCustomerViewModels()
      {
        int skip = 0;
        int take = 100;

        return await _context.Customer.Skip(skip).Take(take)
            .Select(customer => new CustomerViewModel
            {
                CustomerID = customer.CustomerID,
                Code = customer.Code,
                Name = customer.Name
            }).ToListAsync();
       }
    }
 }
```

Once I run the project, I get the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.)

This is because I am not referencing the actual Entity Framework project. I cannot find a good example on the net where the ADO.NET Entity Data Model is implemented in a separate project. How can I achieve this goal? Is there something I need to do in `CustomerDbContext`? Or perhaps it suffices to use the EF `DbContext` class?

Reminder: all the classes listed above are implemented in the API project and not in the Entity Framework project.

Comment: Did you try adding `CustomerDbContext` to **MyEFDataAccess** project? Since you have taken approach to isolate data layer, why not the context class?

Comment: I dont want the EFDataAccess to depond on the WebAPI. This creates a cross reference.

Comment: How does **EDDataAccess** have to depend on **WebAPI** project if you have `CustomerDbContext` in **EDDataAccess**?

Comment: This error has got nothing to do with EF being in separate projects and everything to do with the connection string you've got in your app config.

Comment: Copy the <connectionString /> from App.Config of MyEFDataAccess and paste in web.Config of WebApi project.

Comment: It's not due to a missing connection string. I have already put that in config file. And it's not faulty because when I use the EF context class directly I get correct results.